# Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package - what files does it contain?

Tags: c#, .net, c++

What files does the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package contain ?
I would like to bundle the files with my application.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just bundle the redist with your app?  You're asking for a whole heap of trouble if you try to redist specific DLLs yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually open the redistributable packages with an archive utility and take a look inside. I think [7-zip](http://7-zip.org/) should do the trick here. It should handle both MSI packages and the old CAB package format.

Answer (score 1):

They contain atl, mfc, the c-library, and possibly openmp. On my system they are installed into `C:\Windows\winsxs`. For example:

```
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bdf22a22ab9e15d5
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_b81d038aaf540e86
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.openmp_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_ecdf8c290e547f39
```

In addition to the above I have several other versions installed. It is highly unlikely that all of your customers have all versions installed, so it is indeed a good idea to bundle the correct version with your application.

Daniel